# OpenCV2 in Python throwing error with inRange

Tags: python, opencv

So I looked pretty hard, but I couldn't find much of anything on OpenCV errors, and definitely no documentation discussing possible errors and their causes. I'm using OpenCV2 with Python 2.7, trying to track colored puff balls live with a webcam. To do this, I get the center of a colored ball by thresholding the latest image from the webcam around the HSV values that the puff ball appears as. Unfortunately, this doesn't always seem to work, and throws a very mysterious error:

```
cv2.error: .../matrix.cpp:235: error: (-215) step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags) in function create
```

I have no idea why it would be throwing this. The code that spawns it is:

```
    def getColorCenter(self, imgHSV, lowerBound, upperBound, debugName = None):
        detectedImg = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lowerBound, upperBound)

        if str(lowerBound) == str(self.GREEN_LOWER_BOUND):
            cv2.imshow(str(lowerBound) + "puffball", detectedImg)

        center = self.getCenterOfLargestBlob(detectedImg, debugName)
        return center
```

and in particular the line `detectedImg = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lowerBound, upperBound)`.

Any idea what might solve this issue?

Comment: Question: Are lowerBound and upperBound scalars or arrays? If lowerBound and GREEN_LOWER_BOUND are scalars, why are you converting them to string before comparing them in str(lowerBound) == str(self.GREEN_LOWER_BOUND)?

Comment: They are arrays. Specifically numpy arrays.

Comment: Can you also edit to show how you call getColorCenter?

Answer (score 0):

The error might be caused if the webcam doesn't detect any blobs.

A better approach to your problem would be to use contours.
You can go over all the contours in your image and select the one with largest area. Then you can return the centroid of the largest contour.

```
detectedImg = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lowerBound, upperBound)

# If there is a lot of noise in your image it would help to open and dilate

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))

detectedImg_open = cv2.morphologyEx(detectedImg, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
detectedImg_dilate = cv2.dilate(detectedImg_open, kernel, iterations = 1)
```

Now find the contours :

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(detectedImg_dilate, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Find the largest contour by area:

```
largest_contour_val = 0
largest_contour_pos = 0
for i in xrange(len(contours)):
    if cv2.contourArea(contours[i])>largest_contour_val:
        largest_contour_val = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        largest_contour_pos = i
```

Now only if there exists at least one contour, we return the centroid of the largest contour:

```
if len(contours)!=0:

    # find centroid and return it
    M = cv2.moments(contours[largest_contour_pos])
    x = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    center = (x,y)
    return center
```